# Are there any CubeSats that have been launched into Geostationary (GEO/GSO) or Geostationary Transfer Orbit (GTO)?

Tags: spacecraft, cubesat, geostationary

There is one mission by GSFC/NASA - Shields-1 to be launched into GTO. Apart from that I couldn't find any other mission to GTO/GEO. It would be of great help if there is any information on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No cubesats have yet been launched into GEO or GTO.

Used the database suggested by Matthew, which is a wonderful database - [World's largest database of nano satellites](http://www.nanosats.eu/).

Here are the lists of CubeSat missions planned for GEO and GTO.

1. **SpectroCube** - 3U CubeSat by ESA, planned to be launched in Dec. 2020.
2. **GTOSat** - 6U CubeSat by GSFC, NASA planned to be launched in Dec. 2020.
3. **Orbital Factory II** - 3U CubeSat by Uni. of Texas at El Paso
4. **LACCE** (LousianA Coronal mass ejection Correlation Experiment) - 3U CubeSat by Uni. of Lousiana, Lafayette.
5. **ADE** (Aerodynamic Deorbit Experiment) - 3U CubeSat by Purdue University.
6. **DSM-BRAC** - 2U CubeSat by Uni. of Michigan.
   The last four CubeSats are the winning entries of ULA's STEM education program. They get to hitch-hike to GTO for free!

Cheers to Matthew again! :D

Comment: Thanks sky! At least I helped by providing the link to the data base :P Just a quick question, how did you find out where the CubeSats are going to be launched? Because I just checked the database and found the missions, but I can't tell why they are going to be launched there.

Comment: Done! Better late than never :)

Comment: @sky I just ran across this again by accident, next time don't forget to use the `@username` so that the other person receives a flag. Looks much better now!

Comment: this should be updated (TODO delme)

Answer (score 3):

I have done some research, and I believe that there have been 5 CubeSats that have been launched into Geostationary Orbit.

I have put all those 5 CubeSats together with all the information I found.

[image]

Source is [World's largest database of nano satellites](http://www.nanosats.eu)

***I hope this is what you were asking for :D***

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthew! Special thanks for the link to the database. But unfortunately, the first three CubeSats in the list that have been launched, are launched in LEO. The two other CubeSats are scheduled to be launched in LEO again. Anyways, cheers for the database :)